# How to extract text from a node but not from its children

Tags: nokogiri

I'm trying to parse this fragment with nokogiri from a page(so named a var) that contains

```
...
<dd>
    <a href="http://www.bo.es">Access </a>
    - 19/07/11
</dd>
...
```

`page.at("dd").text` shows me the whole text, not only dd's but also it's descendants text too. I mean

```
"Access - 19/07/11"
```

How can I extract only `"- 19/07/11"`?

(this is only an example)

Answer (score 2):

Try `page.xpath("//dd/text()").text`